# Use MKLocalSearch to populate a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, mkmapview, mklocalsearch

I'm a new programmer. Trying to use the data that is returned in my search to populate a `UITableView`. Currently, I just have to zooming in on the map to an annotated area, but would like to present a table view of information.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearch: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


    var searchResults = [MKMapItem]()

    @IBOutlet weak var myMapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        //Ignoring user
        UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        //Activity Indicator
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        //Hide search bar
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        //Create the search request
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text

        let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)

        activeSearch.start { (response, error) in

            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

            if response == nil
            {
                print("ERROR")
            }
            else
            {
                //Remove annotations
                let annotations = self.myMapView.annotations
                self.myMapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)

                //Getting data
                let latitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
                let longitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude

                //Create annotation
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.title = searchBar.text
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
                self.myMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

                //Zooming in on annotation
                let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
                let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
                self.myMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            }
```